# One-to-one relationship DB Model not working

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

**Background:**

I have a project where users are able to upload files. In the database, I want to store the file path to the uploaded file.

There are 2 tables within the DB; a `Users` & `FileUploadPath`. These tables have a one-to-one relationship.

The Flask-SQLAlchemy model I have currently is:

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////{}'.format(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "test.db"))
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class User(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'Users'

    userid = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    fname = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    lname = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    phonenum = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    validated = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)

    child = db.relationship('FileUploadPath', uselist=False, backref='Users')


class FileUploadPath(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'FileUploadPath'

    fileUploadID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    w9FilePath = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    gcFilePath = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    livescanFilePath = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    gcaFilePath = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)

    userID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Users.userid'))
```

To create a new user I use the following:

```
newuser = User(fname='Bob', lname='Smith', phonenum='6551234567', email='bobsmith@gmail.com', password='fe287943hfbwiqey281')
```

With this command I would expect to see a `userID` within the `FileUploadPath` table; currently seeing only the created user in the `Users` table, but `NULL` inside the `userID` column.

With a query I would also want to see all the uploaded file paths information related to a specific user.

Is the relationship between the model's setup correctly? If not, how would I go about declaring the relationship?

**EDIT:**

What I want to do is store the `fileUploadID` inside of the `Users` table.  A new row inside `FileUploadPath` table should be inserted for every new user that gets created. Because when I create a new user, all columns inside `FileUploadPath` table will be empty; since the new user has not uploaded any files yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table relationships look ok, except that `backref='Users'` is an odd choice of name, as this will add a "Users" property to the `FileUploadPath`, which doesn't follow the naming convention of the rest of its properties. I would have expected this to be `backref='user'` instead.

Now, the main problem is that you haven't specified a `FileUploadPath` that `newuser` should be associated with, so it hasn't inserted any entry in `FileUploadPath` that references the ID of `newuser`. Or maybe you have inserted a new `FileUploadPath` that you intended to be linked to `newuser`, though you haven't shown that code in your example. In any case, it doesn't know which `FileUploadPath` to associate with which `User`, and it doesn't automatically create a new `FileUploadPath` for each `User`, and so when you only create a new `User`, or if you individually create new `User` and `FileUploadPath` but don't link them, you don't end up with a `FileUploadPath` associated with your new `User`.

So, what you need to do is to link a `FileUploadPath` to `newuser` either by adding a `child=newFileUploadPath` parameter (where `newFileUploadPath` is the already constructed `FileUploadPath` object) when you call the `User` constructor, or by individually constructing and adding the `User` and `FileUploadPath` objects, and setting `newuser.child = newFileUploadPath`, or `newFileUploadPath.user = newuser`. (Note that `newFileUploadPath.user` assumes my suggested `backref='user'` change.)

**Edit:** Here's an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows how to add a file upload for a user. But the file upload does not exist when the user is initially created, which should be the expected behaviour. You definitely should not have an entry in `FileUploadPath` that contains all empty strings. Also, if you plan to allow up to 4 uploads per user, you need to make it a many-to-one relationship instead, by getting rid of that `uselist=False` and treating `Users.child` as a list, and maybe also renaming it to `children` or `uploads`.

(Note, this example uses plain SQLAlchemy rather than Flask-SQLAlchemy, so some parts of the Model definition and database setup may appear different to your implementation.)

```
import os
import sys
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, Boolean
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Users'

    userid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    fname = Column(String(80), nullable=False)
    lname = Column(String(80), nullable=False)
    phonenum = Column(String(10), nullable=False)
    email = Column(String(60), nullable=False)
    password = Column(String(60), nullable=False)
    validated = Column(Boolean, default=False)

    child = relationship('FileUploadPath', uselist=False, backref='user')


class FileUploadPath(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'FileUploadPath'

    fileUploadID = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    w9FilePath = Column(String(60), nullable=False)
    gcFilePath = Column(String(60), nullable=False)
    livescanFilePath = Column(String(60), nullable=False)
    gcaFilePath = Column(String(60), nullable=False)

    userID = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Users.userid'))

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///')
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = session_factory()

# Insert a new user with no uploads:
newuser = User(fname='Bob', lname='Smith', phonenum='6551234567', email='bobsmith@gmail.com', password='fe287943hfbwiqey281')
session.add(newuser)
session.commit()

# Query for users and uploads:
print(session.query(FileUploadPath).count())
# 0

print(session.query(User).count())
# 1

print(session.query(User).one().child)
# None

# Insert an upload for the user:
newupload = FileUploadPath(w9FilePath='some_path', gcFilePath='another_path', livescanFilePath='yet_another_path', gcaFilePath='another_path_still', user=newuser)
session.add(newupload)
session.commit()

# Again, query for users and uploads:
print(session.query(FileUploadPath).count())
# 1

print(session.query(User).one().child)
# <FileUploadPath object>

print(session.query(User).one().child.w9FilePath)
# 'some_path'
```

Comment: See the edit I have made to the post, I tried to clarify what exactly I want to accomplish. It would be a little easier to understand your logic in code format. Maybe you could try to take my code I posted and show a visual example? That would really help, thanks.

Comment: Can a single user make multiple uploads? If so, you can't store `fileUploadID` in the `Users` table. Even if each user may only have one upload, this still seems like a bad idea, as you have stated that a new user will have zero uploads, and so from that perspective it makes more sense to have `FileUploadPath` contain the user ID, rather than `Users` contain the file upload ID. (Or did you mean that `FileUploadPath` should still contain the user ID, but you merely want to be able to get a file upload ID from a `Users` entry?)

Comment: A single user is required to upload 4 submission, but those 4 submissions do not have to happen at the same time. They can upload files one at a time after they have logged into their account. Then every time a user uploads a file, I want to store that path inside of the `fileUploadsPath` table.

Comment: Ok, then you definitely shouldn't be creating an empty `FileUploadPath` when the user is first created. Just create them as the file uploads occur. I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Thank you for your edit, this way makes sense and has solved my issue.